# How do you handle unbalanced image datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, datasets, imbalanced-datasets

I have an image data set on which I am training a CNN. The data set is slightly unbalanced. So, my solution up till now was to delete some images of the majority class.

But I now realize that there are cleaner ways to deal with this. But I haven't been able to find ways to fix unbalanced *image* data sets. Only *structured* data-sets.

I would like someone to guide me to fix the unbalance, other than deleting data from the majority class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always adjust [class weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#class_weights) accordingly. I know the reference is not for image data but it shouldn't matter if you are doing classification. [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras) is another answer more direct to the point.